# The URL given through the AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate function unable to be played

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, playback

I'm trying to create a Snapchat-like app where the user can take a video by holding down a button. However, when the user is done taking a video, and the delegate calls `fileOutput`, the given url `outputFileURL` cannot be played using an AVPlayer. I know that the video was actually recorded though, because I can upload the file to Firebase and download it from there.

Here's my code for the `fileOutput` function:

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    if error == nil {
        videoURL = outputFileURL
        flipHiddenViews()

        // playback video
        player = AVPlayer(url: outputFileURL)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        player?.play()
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Here's how I initialize the button that the user holds down:

```
let photoButton:UIButton = {
    let but = UIButton(type: .custom)
    but.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    but.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    but.layer.borderWidth = 4
    but.clipsToBounds = true
    but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(takeVideo), for: .touchDown)
    but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopVideo), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
    but.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return but
}()
```

Here's the `takeVideo` function:

```
@objc func takeVideo() {
    let recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self
    if captureSession?.outputs != nil && videoFileOutput != nil {
        captureSession?.removeOutput(videoFileOutput!)
    }
    videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    self.captureSession?.addOutput(videoFileOutput!)

    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp")

    // Do recording and save the output to the `filePath`
    videoFileOutput?.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate!)
}
```

And finally, the `stopVideo` function:

```
@objc func stopVideo() {
    videoFileOutput?.stopRecording()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please specify _"cannot be played"_. Due you receive any errors/warnings? Or does the `AVPlayer` simply never finish loading the video?

Comment: Does giving the URL filename a .mov suffix help?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I don't receive any errors or warnings, but it seems the AVPlayer can't get the data for the video. When I try to just present the AVPlayer using an `AVPlayerViewController`, there's a line through the play button

Comment: @RhythmicFistman lemme try that

Comment: @RhythmicFistman adding ".mov" fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Great, in that case accept your answer?

Comment: I can only accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
// playback video
player = AVPlayer(url: outputFileURL)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
present(playerController, animated: true) {
    player?.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `.mov` at the end of the "temp" name did it for me:

```
let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp.mov")
```